# Show that the set $A = \{x \in \mathbb R: \sin(x) \neq x\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt:

A' has a single value.

Since sin(x) = x has only one solution x=0.
Therefore every nonzero real number is an element of A. Therefore A is open

Comment: You are right! Indeed $\sin x <x$ for all $x >0$ so $\sin\,x =x$ implies $x=0$.

Comment: Maybe try this generalization: Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be continuous, then $\{x\in\mathbb R: f(x)\neq0\}$ is open.

Comment: I usually just think like so: $A=(-\infty,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$ and that uses $()$ which means open

Answer (score 3):

It’s well-known fact that for continuous function $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, where $U$ is open. So in your case just take $U = \mathbb{R}  \setminus \{0\}$ and $f(x) = \sin(x)-x$